# What is the difference between the return function and storing a variable?

Tags: java, return

I'm learning how to code in Java. I'm a little confused by "return;" and what it does and when we use it. Please see the following example of code:

```
public int something() { 
    return 1; 
} 

public static void main() { 
    int returnValue = something(); 
    System.out.println(returnValue); 
    //Prints 1 
}
```

Why wouldn't we just store 1 into a int variable called something then use `System.out.print(something);`

When would we use the return method instead of simply storing into a variable?

Thank you

Comment: `add(1,2);` How do you propose we get the value 3 out of this method without a return function?

Comment: What if `something()` is doing something a whole lot more complicated than just `return 1`?  You can't just assign `1`, since you don't know `1` is what you want to return until you've done all the work.

Comment: If have a lot of options to return from 'something() ' your variable cannot store only the value 1, if so it's not even a variable, it's a constant.

Comment: Who down-voted this question? The guy is new with Java. Give him a break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you could store into a variable but then you would lose one of the very important features, namely the ability to call the method inside itself.

This is relevant for algorithms that divide the work into smaller chunks and invoke themselves on the smaller chunks (and then combine the individual result to a big result).  This is very common in sorting algorithms.  The technical term is *recursion*.

Usually the compiler actually *does* exactly this; creates a variable for storing the value from where the calling code can pick it up.  This variable is typically put in the same location - the *stack* - as the parameters passed in to the called method, and is invisible to your code.

(Also it is needed to make it threadsafe which is essential to utilizing more than one core on a modern cpu).

Comment: This explained it perfectly, Thank you!